# c# linq - SelectMany - An expression tree lambda may not contain a dictionary initializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to fetch records from the table and converting it into dictionary but getting error while casting into `Dictionary<int, List<WorkpaperClientDetail>>` using selectmany operator.

Getting error - An expression tree lambda may not contain a dictionary initializer.

```
var asd = uow.WorkpaperRepo.GetAllNoTracking(expression)
    .SelectMany(wps => new Dictionary<int, List<WorkpaperClientDetail>>
    {
        [wps.WorkpaperId] = wps.AccountMap.AccountMappings.Select(y => new WorkpaperClientDetail
        {
            AccountName = y.ClientAccount.Description,
            AccountNumber = y.ClientAccount.Code
        }).ToList()
    }).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary initializer that starts with `[wps.WorkpaperId] = wps.AccountMap ...` ? I don't know what you are trying to do here but this should work as expected:

```
Dictionary<int, List<WorkpaperClientDetail>> asd = uow.WorkpaperRepo.GetAllNoTracking(expression)
    .Select(wps => new{ wps.WorkpaperId, ClientList = wps.AccountMap.AccountMappings
        .Select(y => new WorkpaperClientDetail
        {
            AccountName = y.ClientAccount.Description,
            AccountNumber = y.ClientAccount.Code
        })
        .ToList() })
   .ToDictionary(x => x.WorkpaperId, x => x.ClientList);
```

Comment: getting error on SelectMany - cannot be inferred from the usage. try specifying the the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: error - an expression tree may not contain a tuple literal - Please check again

Comment: @Ronak: it seems your Linq provider does not (yet) support tuples. Then use anonymous types. Will edit it... Done

Comment: @TimSchmelter, it is not depended on provider. Currently compiler do not allow tuples in Expression tree.

Comment: Linq2Objects supported because it is not expression tree. In `Queryable` extension unfortunately compiler won't compile tuples. And yes, EF Core may not translate tuples if they are not available via pure C# code.